# Intranet site where each department can view their information

Tags: web-apps, project-management, intranet

Im looking to setup an intranet site where my employees can quickly view notes and/or information on an intranet.

My portal "vision" is

- To do list
- Next buyers
- Installers

Although it is very vague, maybe there are some options out there I could look at.

I looked at SharePoint but its price is too high for a small business.

**Note**: Everyone should post their information, for example:

- Someone from sales is going to sell something.
- Information from that sale who, where when, how much, should be posted by that person.
- Once posted, everyone in sales should be able to see it, add comments, etc.

Comment: Worry less about setting this up initially than about maintaining it. How will you update the content & who will do so? Also, does everyone get access to everything, or do you need login with different roles, corresponding to who can view/edit/delete which pieces of information?

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same shoes like you. Sharepoint was too expensive for me and I was unable to deploy it. I personally think intranet especially for small business should be low cost.

I run a small business with 40 staff in a service industry. I settled for [**Precurio Intranet**](http://www.precurio.com/precurio-intranet-trial-campaign/).

It is low cost and it can help in to-do list and installer some of the needs you have. Been using it for 3 years now.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org) based distribution named [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium). Here is a partial quote from its project page:

> ... intended as an extensible collaboration framework. Adds the ability to have private "sections" within a collaboration space with granular access control. Drag/drop layout control with dozens of widgets that can be placed on dashboards and landing pages. Comes with Discussions, Events, Files, Issue tracking, and Document Wiki out of the box, along with the dashboards to manage it all.

Looking at your specs/requirements, I can't find anything in your question that you can't do with it (out of the OpenAtrium box). What is more: there are tons of other things you could add to your requirements which are pretty forward to also implement/enable. Obviously, it will help if you have some Drupal experience (or are willing to hire somebody to get you going).

It's opensource and free of any license cost, and a possible alternative for Sharepoint. What more would you want?